# Interpreting DNA Match of 947cM at AncestryDNA

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis

I am 75 years old.

I have a known 1st cousin who matches 756  cM with me.

I also have an unknown 1st-2nd cousin who matches 947 cM with me and is 44 years younger than me.

What relation could this 1st-2nd cousin be to me?

Comment: Hi Pauline, welcome. I'm not quite sure what your question is, could you please [edit] your question to include a bit more detail? In the meantime I will close the question. 947 cM could represent a number of different relationships (you can enter this number here to see different possible relationships - https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4). It really is a matter of trying to contact the DNA match or looking at their family tree to determine where the common ancestor might be.

Comment: Hi Harry, I am a newbie at ancestry, and was just confused really at the ages gap.              my closest match says they are 1-2nd cousins and my second closes match is a known cousin, but he closest match is 45 years younger than me. and I was wondering if I am not seeing why. I have looked in their tree and cant see a connection. But the 45 years dont make sense really.

Comment: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/947 suggests some relationships other than 1st cousin (and seems to rule out 2nd cousin) that this person may have to you.  Some of those could fit with your age difference but age difference may be able to rule out some others.